# What is the real price of a Druid's Vestment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, druid, errata, pricing

A Druid's Vestment doesn't take up a body slot and grants one Wild shape more per day. The tables with the wondrous items in the DMG say its price is 3750 gp while the item description says  10000 gp. I also looked in the PFSRD and there both entries say 3750 gp. So what should be the correct price?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Market price for the [*druid's vestment*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#vestmentDruids) is 10,000 gp.

The 2012 printing of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* gives the *druid's vestment* market price in both table and text as 10,000 gp, unlike the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2003), wherein the *druid's vestment* is listed in the table as having a market price of 3,750 gp but in the text as having a market price of 10,000 gp.

The 2012 printing of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* is, as of this writing, the latest printing and officially supersedes all others if that sort of thing is important somehow.

---

Because I started looking through the tables, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012) deleted the *druid's vestment* from Table 7–27: Minor Wondrous Items, moving entry 58 to 57, 59 to 58, and so on and making the 100 result *Roll Again*. The *druid's vestment* was added to Table 7–28: Medium Wondrous Items at the text's price point of 10,000 gp (the table accommodating the *vestment* with the deletion of the *talisman of the sphere* where it was listed in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2003) as having a market price of 9,000 gp but presented on page 209 as a priceless minor artifact). The table adjusted at least one other pricing irregularity as well, that of the [*necklace of fireballs, type VII*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#necklaceofFireballs) (the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012) now listing market price in table and text as 8,700 gp).

Comment: Is there a complete list of such changes? If not, would you be interested in answering that as a question here?

Comment: @fectin So far as I'm aware, the premium edition core rulebooks' stealth errata are undocumented—find changes requires setting versions of the book side by side then going line by line. I kid you not. And, of course, mistakes remain (e.g. the *DMG* still referring to the *power word* spells as spells of the Conjuration school). It would be a monumental task for each core rulebook that I'd be unwilling to undertake but would more than happily upvote.

Comment: Totally reasonable! I admire how you have the highest willingness of any regular to undertake such tasks, but if your willingness is low it seems unlikely to happen.  Let me think about whether such a question is reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

All errata for 3.5 can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata). However, the errata for the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* does not mention the *druid’s vestment* specifically. What it **does** mention is that, if a table does not match the text of an item’s specific entry, you should favor the text (known as “text-trumps-table” in 3.5 circles). Thus, the *druid’s vestment* officially costs 10,000 gp, which is accurately reflected on [Table: Medium Wondrous Items](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#tableMediumWondrousItems) on d20srd.org.

Pathfinder, being a separate game, is free to do things differently; apparently Paizo decided that the 3,750 gp figure was more appropriate for this item. Considering the significant changes to Wild Shape in Pathfinder, however, which make it much weaker than it was in 3.5, it makes sense that it would be much cheaper.